# 2 rigs in one object

Tags: modeling, rigging, objects, armature, motion-capture

I would like to rig my object in the style of a two person horse suit.

[image]

So two separate rigs for one object.
I'll be using it for mocap later with two people.
I tried just putting two separate ones and simply parenting, but every time one of them gets detached.
Help is extremely appreciated!